# How to integrate Weld to the maven project?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

Trying to import this projects (With Weld) and it can`t

```
import org.jboss.weld.environment.se
```

to use Weld class in project.

https://github.com/agoncal/agoncal-book-javaee7

Comment: are you trying to deploy a webapp or an SE application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on what you are trying to achieve. 
Are you writing a Java EE web application (war/ear) or a standalone app?
Also: Weld is the reference implementation of CDI and CDI is just a part of Java EE. If you use CDI only (by setting up weld-se), you cannot use EJB/EntityManager/Transactional/... , its "just" CDI.

That all being said: using weld-se in a java standalone application can be done by importing

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
  <artifactId>weld-se</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.6.Final</version>
 </dependency>
```

Bootstrapping the application "Main.class" is done via

```
    // Initialize Weld
    Weld theWeld = new Weld();
    WeldContainer theContainer = theWeld.initialize();


    // Execute the run method
    theContainer.instance().select(Main.class).get().run();


    // Shutting down Weld again
    theWeld.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 0):

According this book at first you should install aplication server to run your applications. In your case it will be Glassfish. 
The same question were discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705017/weld-not-initializing-properly).

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried to run a sample from this book without any modifications.
The reason it does not work is that non-existing Weld version is specified in the `<dependency>` block:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
  <artifactId>weld-se</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

Just compare with the list of available versions and ensure the version `2.0.0` is not present here: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/weld/se/weld-se/

You can use any other version, for example

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
  <artifactId>weld-se</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```